# Touchpad cursor inertia

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

When using my synaptics touchpad on Windows, the driver has the option of giving the cursor inertia (note, not just the scrolling).

I found it a lot less straining to use the touchpad with this feature enabled. You could 'fling' your finger in a direction and zoom across the screen quickly instead of 'treading through mud' to get there.

So is there any way of getting cursor inertia on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: This is called "coasting", and should be configurable with `synclient`. [Synaptics manpages](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html) have the details.

Comment: @Norrius Synaptics "coasting" property relates to scrolling, not flinging the pointer itself with inertia. Same questions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/564488/synaptics-touchpad-how-to-activate-the-cursor-momentum-not-scrolling-momentum?noredirect=1&lq=1