# Synaptics touchpad: how to activate the cursor Momentum (NOT scrolling Momentum)

Tags: synaptics

I'm not sure if the feature I want to activate is called Momentum. I want the cursor to continue moving in a direction like I'm pushing a ball. If I push the ball softy, it will continue moving a little bit after I lift my finger from the touch pad. If I push the ball harder, it will continue moving faster and further.

I have tried the command of the accepted answer of the following question, but that answer if for the scrolling Momentum and not for the cursor Momentum: [How do I enable mouse momentum after release in kde/gnome/unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493377/how-do-i-enable-mouse-momentum-after-release-in-kde-gnome-unity)

If we type: `synclient | grep Momentum`, we can't see any related command to activate the Momentum feature.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: Check [`man synaptics`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man4/synaptics.4.html) and see if it has an option for it there. e.g. 'CornerCoasting' means 'Enable edge scrolling to continue while the finger stays  in  an edge corner.'

Comment: @Wilf reading your comment I guess the feature I want to activate is not Edge Motion. Please, read the description. Do you know how this feature is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is missing. You would need the Synaptic Gesture Suite which only OEMs have access to.

I really hope that at some point this will change. Someone please post here if it does!

Source: [Turn on Touchpad Momentum feature in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323411/turn-on-touchpad-momentum-feature-in-ubuntu)

---

Other related Questions about this:

[Touchpad cursor inertia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235630/touchpad-cursor-inertia?rq=1)

https://superuser.com/questions/63681/kinetic-scrolling-in-linux-and-synaptics (Neil Santos)